# Randomly capitalize letters in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, uppercase, lowercase

I want to randomly capitalize or lowercase each letter in a string. I'm new to working with strings in python, but I think because strings are immutable that I can't do the following:

```
i =0             
for c in sentence:
    case = random.randint(0,1)
    print("case = ", case)
    if case == 0:
        print("here0")
        sentence[i] = sentence[i].lower()
    else:
        print("here1")
        sentence[i] = sentence[i].upper()
    i += 1
print ("new sentence = ", sentence)
```

And get the error: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

But then how else could I do this?

Comment: Use another container, like a `list`, then create the string from that. Alternatively, create a new sting incrementally

Comment: You can always create a new String with randomized caps and small letters.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `str.join` with a generator expression like this:

```
from random import choice
sentence = 'Hello World'
print(''.join(choice((str.upper, str.lower))(c) for c in sentence))
```

Sample output:

```
heLlo WORLd
```

Comment: Aren't list comprehensions faster with join?

Comment: No, list comprehension would be slower because it would materialize all item values first to form a list before passing the list to `join`, resulting in more overhead in both time and memory. With a generator expression, the `join` method would be able to simply iterate through the generator output as the generator produces item values one by one.

Comment: Nice.., thanks for telling me

Comment: @U9-Forward You are correct. `join` needs a list, so giving it a list in the first place is faster than giving it a generator. [Authoritative reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/3620003).

Comment: @timgeb Oh i am right, wow, now i know :-)

Comment: @timgeb I stand corrected then. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Build a new string.

Here's a solution with little changes to your original code:

```
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> def randomcase(s):
...:    result = ''
...:    for c in s:
...:        case = random.randint(0, 1)
...:        if case == 0:
...:            result += c.upper()
...:        else:
...:            result += c.lower()
...:    return result
...:
...:
>>> randomcase('Hello Stackoverflow!')
>>> 'hElLo StaCkoVERFLow!'
```

edit: deleted my oneliners because I like blhsing's better.

Answer (score 4):

```
import random
sentence='quick test'
print(''.join([char.lower() if random.randint(0,1) else char.upper() \
                   for char in sentence]))
```

> qUiCK TEsT

Comment: you can pass your list to `''join()` for a more complete solution

Comment: Although this answer works for me just as well as the one by @blhsing, it's a little bit less performant.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the string implementation to a list implementation. As string is immutable, you cannot change the value inside the object. But `Lists` can be, So I've only changed that part of your code. And make note that there are much better ways to do this, Follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018539/convert-random-characters-in-a-string-to-uppercase)

```
import random
sentence = "This is a test sentence" # Strings are immutable
i =0
new_sentence = [] # Lists are mutable sequences
for c in sentence:
    case = random.randint(0,1)
    print("case = ", case)
    if case == 0:
        print("here0")
        new_sentence += sentence[i].lower() # append to the list
    else:
        print("here1")
        new_sentence += sentence[i].upper() # append to the list
    i += 1
print ("new sentence = ", new_sentence)

# to print as string
new_sent = ''.join(new_sentence)
print(new_sent)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below

```
char_list = []            
for c in sentence:
    ucase = random.randint(0,1)
    print("case = ", case)
    if ucase:
        print("here1")
        char_list.append(c.upper())
    else:
        print("here0")
        char_list.append(c.lower())
print ("new sentence = ", ''.join(char_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way without involving python loop would be sending it to numpy and do vectorized operation over that. For example:

```
import numpy as np
def randomCapitalize(s):
    s  = np.array(s, 'c').view('u1')
    t  = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(s), 'u1') # Temporary array
    t *= s != 32 # ASCII 32 (i.e. space) should not be lowercased
    t *= 32 # Decrease ASCII by 32 to lowercase
    s -= t
    return s.view('S' + str(len(s)))[0]
randomCapitalize('hello world jfwojeo jaiofjowejfefjawivj a jofjawoefj')
```

which outputs:

```
b'HELLO WoRlD jFwoJEO JAioFjOWeJfEfJAWIvJ A JofjaWOefj'
```

This solution should be reasonably fast especially for long string. There are two limitations of this method:

- The input must be fully lower case. You can try `.lower()` it first but thats technically low efficient.
- It need special care for non-a-to-z character. In the example above, only space is handled

You can handle a lot more special characters at the same time by replacing

```
t *= s != 32
```

with

```
# using space, enter, comma, period as example
t *= np.isin(s, list(map(ord, ' \n,.')), invert=True)
```

For example:

```
s = 'ascii table and description. ascii stands for american standard code for information interchange. computers can only understand numbers, so an ascii code is the numerical representation of a character such as'
randomCapitalize(s)
```

which outputs:

```
b'ascII tABLe AnD descRiptIOn. ascii sTaNds for AmEricAN stanDaRD codE FOr InForMAtION iNTeRCHaNge. ComPUtERS can onLY UNdersTand nUMBers, So An asCIi COdE IS tHE nuMERIcaL rEPrEsEnTATion Of a CHaractEr such as'
```

Comment: Hey if something is wrong I'll fix it. Would you at least leave a comment for reason of downvote?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but i presume the issue is bringing Numpy and vectorised whatnot into a situation where the OP just needs to learn about mutable versus immutable containers.