# Code that randomly capitalizes each letter of a string (Code cleaning help)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner coder, and I recently created a function that takes a string and randomly capitalizes each letter.

```
def rand_upper(string):
    import random
    strList = [l for l in string.lower()] 
    newList = []
    for i in strList:
        j = random.randrange(2)
        if j == 1:
            letter = i.upper()
            newList.append(letter)
        else:
            newList.append(i)
    return "".join(newList)
```

The code works as I intended, but is there any way that I can make this code cleaner? I personally think this is hard to read. Are there any other ways to compress the code to make it more readable/efficient? thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: And anyway, a duplicate: [Randomly capitalize letters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942497/randomly-capitalize-letters-in-string)

Comment: @Tomerikoo While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus* (as I have done here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: [import statements always be at the top of a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thanks for that link! Duly noted. Anyway, it's a duplicate

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you for the tip! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomly capitalize letters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942497/randomly-capitalize-letters-in-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mastering generator expressions is a great way to make code like this shorter:

```
from random import randrange

def rand_upper(string: str) -> str:
    return "".join(
        c.upper() if randrange(2) else c.lower() 
        for c in string
    )
```

```
>>> rand_upper("Sphinx of black quartz, witness my vow!")
'sPhiNx of BlacK qUARTz, wiTnEsS mY VOw!'
```

The general trick is that any time you're building a list by `append`ing one element at a time, there's probably a way that you could do it more simply as a list comprehension, by writing an expression that generates each element of the list.

If you're not actually returning the list, and are instead passing it to a function that accepts any iterable (e.g. `str.join`), you can leave out the list part (the `[]`) and just pass the generator expression directly to that function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52942584/6045800

Comment: Actually, with `str.join` [it is better to pass a list than a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/6045800)

Answer (score 7):

Using `choice` instead, and calling `lower` and `upper` only once.

```
from random import choice

def rand_upper(string):
    return ''.join(map(choice, zip(string.lower(), string.upper())))
```

Even better, as [Peter commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186066/code-that-randomly-capitalizes-each-letter-of-a-string-code-cleaning-help/65186379?noredirect=1#comment115242383_65186169):

```
def rand_upper(string):
    return ''.join(map(choice, zip(string, string.swapcase())))
```

Another, based on [Olvin_Roght's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65186379/13008439):

```
def rand_upper(string):
    return ''.join([c if getrandbits(1) else c.swapcase() for c in string])
```

Two more, mixing our solutions for the fastest so far:

```
def rand_upper(string):
    return ''.join([c if getrandbits(1) else d
                    for c, d in zip(string, string.swapcase())])
```

```
def rand_upper(string):
    return ''.join([z[getrandbits(1)] for z in zip(string, string.swapcase())])
```

Benchmark using `string = rand_upper('a' * 1000)`:

```
739 μs  797 μs  725 μs  original
764 μs  787 μs  693 μs  original_2
713 μs  691 μs  680 μs  Samwise
699 μs  657 μs  682 μs  theCoder
477 μs  486 μs  490 μs  superb_rain
520 μs  476 μs  489 μs  Peter_Wood
135 μs  131 μs  141 μs  based_on_Olvin_Roght
120 μs  113 μs  121 μs  superb_Peter_Olvin
125 μs  117 μs  118 μs  superb_Peter_Olvin_2
```

(Not including Olvin's original because it's the only one with quadratic instead of linear time, so a comparison with a single size would be misleading.)

Code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from random import randrange, choice, getrandbits

def original(string):
    import random
    strList = [l for l in string.lower()] 
    newList = []
    for i in strList:
        j = random.randrange(2)
        if j == 1:
            letter = i.upper()
            newList.append(letter)
        else:
            newList.append(i)
    return "".join(newList)

def original_2(string):
    strList = [l for l in string.lower()] 
    newList = []
    for i in strList:
        j = randrange(2)
        if j == 1:
            letter = i.upper()
            newList.append(letter)
        else:
            newList.append(i)
    return "".join(newList)

def Samwise(string: str) -> str:
    return "".join(
        c.upper() if randrange(2) else c.lower() 
        for c in string
    )

def theCoder(string):
    return ''.join(choice((str.upper, str.lower))(c) for c in string)

def superb_rain(string):
    return ''.join(map(choice, zip(string.lower(), string.upper())))

def Peter_Wood(string):
    return ''.join(map(choice, zip(string, string.swapcase())))

def based_on_Olvin_Roght(string):
    return ''.join([c if getrandbits(1) else c.swapcase() for c in string])

def superb_Peter_Olvin(string):
    return ''.join([c if getrandbits(1) else d for c, d in zip(string, string.swapcase())])

def superb_Peter_Olvin_2(string):
    return ''.join([z[getrandbits(1)] for z in zip(string, string.swapcase())])

funcs = original, original_2, Samwise, theCoder, superb_rain, Peter_Wood, based_on_Olvin_Roght, superb_Peter_Olvin, superb_Peter_Olvin_2

string = original('a' * 1000)
number = 1000

tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for _ in range(4):
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(string), number=number)) / number
        ts.append(t)
        print(*('%d μs ' % (1e6 * t) for t in ts[1:]), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Nice. You could just call `swapcase` once instead of both `lower` and `upper`

Comment: @PeterWood Right, forgot about that one. Added.

Answer (score 1):

**Efficient one(may be)**

```
from random import choice
def rand_upper(string):
    return ''.join(choice((str.upper, str.lower))(c) for c in string)
```

**output in my pc:**

```
>>print(rand_upper('ajskdlfhkalsdfhlkasjdfkajsdfhklasjdfkhaksjhdjkkaljsdf'))
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52942594/6045800

Answer (score 1):

You can generate bit mask using [`random.getrandbits()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits) and apply [`str.swapcase()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) only on `1` bit:

```py
from random import getrandbits

s = "teststring"
mask = getrandbits(len(s))
res = "".join(1 << i & mask and c.swapcase() or c for i, c in enumerate(s))
```

Comment: Turns out using `getrandbits` is a great idea but applying `swapcase` only on 1-bits is not a good idea, see the newest additions to my answer.

Comment: @superbrain, great. You're good in fights with python interpreter :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
from random import choice

def rand_upper(string):
    return ''.join(choice([i.upper(), i]) for i in string.lower())

print(rand_upper("Hello World!"))
```

---

Explanation:

This line:

```
''.join(choice([i.upper(), i]) for i in string.lower())
```

is the conversion of the list `[choice([i.upper(), i]) for i in string.lower()]` into a string. `[choice([i.upper(), i])` returns randomly the uppercase of `i`, or just `i` *(which is lower-cased)*.